# How can I specify what calendar to save e-mailed meeting invites?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I am using Outlook 2013. I used to have just one Calendar and whenever someone e-mailed me a meeting invite (via a `.ics` attachment) I could just double click the attachment then click the Copy to Calendar button and it would copy it to my calendar.

[image: Copy to My Calendar]

But recently, I got an additional Office 365 email address and have integrated that into Outlook. This has added another "mailbox" with its own calendar. Now whenever I click the Copy to My Calendar button for a meeting invite it copies it to my Office 365 calendar in Outlook.

Once this happens, I have to display both calendars in Outlook and then drag the meeting invite from the Office 365 calendar to my personal one and choose to Move it.

This works, I guess, but what I'd like is the ability to specify a default calendar in Outlook or, better yet, have some way that when I accept a meeting invite I can choose which calendar it will be placed under.

Thanks

Comment: Is the Office 365 account set as the default account in your current Outlook profile? By default, when clicking the "Copy to My Calendar" button, or double click the .ics file, the event will be added to your default calendar.

Comment: @SteveFan - my personal account was set as the Default Email account, but under the Data Files tab, it had the Office 365 account as the default. I think that will fix the issue - a million thanks. Did you want to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Good to hear that!! I'll post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in comment, when clicking the "Copy to My Calendar" button, or double click the .ics file, the event will by default be added to your default calendar. Go to File > Account Settings, make sure your personal account and the associated data file are both set as default under Email tab and Data Files tab.